# ASP.NET Color periode of days in calendar without DayRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, calendar

I am trying to make a rental system where the rented days color red, without a ondayrender function. I can't find out how to color the specific date red without the ondayrender.

```
 protected void fillCalendar()
    {
        if (startdates != null && enddates != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            DateTime startdate = startdates[i];
            DateTime enddate = enddates[i];
            while (startdate <= enddate)
            {
                //Color date red

                startdate = startdate.AddDays(1);
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: There's not enough code here for us to be able to help. Please add your ASP.NET code here as well.

Comment: I just need to know how to change the color of the date without the ondayrender, the asp.net code is just the calendar

Comment: Is it possible to use javascript functions, put the relevant logs on the form, and set the color through javascript functions, for example
                function myFunction() {
                 var box = document.getElementById("box");
                 box.style.backgroundColor = "red";
               }